# Length mismatch error reading csv properly and renaming columns

Tags: python, csv

Fresh to coding and already hitting a wall. I have a set of data that uses ';' as a delimiter.
It shows a date and time; a location; and a measurement which can be integer or floating point number:

Example:
2023-06-16 05:45:49;Hall;8

I am trying to organize the columns so I can run statistical analyses on all points in a column (mean, SD etc..) but can't get columns to be recognized. Here is where I am:

```
import pandas as pd
result_file_path = 'D:/Room/Temp_2.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(result_file_path, sep=';', header=None)
data.columns = ['date', 'room', 'result']
data.describe()
```

But then I get the error: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 3 elements

I've tried a few different ways to get the labels to stick but it appears the separator defined isn't finding the splits in the data. If I print the head prior to running data.columns, then I get a 0 in the column area.

```
                       0
```

0  2023-06-16 05:45:49;hall;8
1  2023-06-27 04:36:59;room;8

When I open the csv in notepad, it appears like this:
"2023-09-01 08:18:58;gym;8"
"2023-09-07 06:21:16;room1;8"
"2023-09-12 06:38:45;hall;8"
"2023-06-15 06:12:54;room1;9"
"2023-06-19 00:36:33;hall;9"

Comment: You should open the file with a dumb text editor (notepad) and show here the first lines.